# Как получить локальный ip адрес машины в Java EE

Tags: java, java-ee, ip

Как получить локальный адрес машины в вебсервере Java EE? Внешний я могу получить, а вот именно локальный. Тобишь человек подключается на сайт и я хочу на сервере вытянуть его локальный ip, в его сети. Знаю что такое можно сделать на JS, а можно ли на Java?

Comment: Вот ответ на английском https://stackoverflow.com/a/9482369/5506820

Comment: Думаю на JS Вы можете вытянуть, если с клиента отправится, по сути сервер ограничен тем, что шлет ему клиент. Клиент не прислал, сервер не получил.

Comment: @Темкатоже не работает. не то берет. Он берет адрес машины на котором запущен сервер

Comment: К сожалению, не сразу понял вопрос. Вообще такой возможности со стороны сервера нет и не будет, т.к. это противоречит самой концепции. Однако можно воспользоваться возможностями клиента (javascript), описанными в https://stackoverflow.com/a/26850789/5506820, и передавать в запросе (можно в дополнительном http-заголовке) полученный IP. Но это работает только в Chrome и Firefox/